# Com Jquery pegar todos os elementos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Olá eu queria com Jquery pegar todos os **product_payment** de uma loja e mudar.

Mudando: À vista R$ 137,66 com desconto ou 12x com juros de R$ 13,69.
Para: À vista R$ 137,66 com desconto ou 12x de R$ 13,69.

Tem que ser por Jquery, pois não tenho acesso ao código. (Somente consigo utilizar Javascript para mudar)

```
<div id="product_payment"> <br>
    <span class="txt-avista"> à <span> vista </span></span>
    <strong class="preco-avista precoAvista">R$
        <span>
            <span>137<span>,<span>66</span></span></span>
        </span>
    </strong>
    <span class="txt-com-desconto"> com <span> desconto </span></span>
    <!-- ||137.66|0.00|144.90|11_09_-15_57_59|80 --><br>
    <span class="preco-parc2">
        <span class="txt-corparcelas">ou
            <strong class="color">12x </strong>
            <span class="preco-parc2"><span class="txt-comjurosde"> com juros </span> de
                <strong>R$
                    <span>
                        <span>13<span>,<span>69</span></span></span>
                    </span>
                </strong>
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Como posso mudar o conteúdo do da div utilizando Jquery?

Comment: Por que não tem acesso ao código ?

Comment: Simples, estou usando o twig, é um e-commerce. Nem tudo dá para mudar no HTML.

Comment: Você tem acesso ao FTP e a árvore de pastas ? Tem acesso ao JS, mas não ao HTML ? ...

Comment: É assim que funciona Diego Souza, alguns E-commerce usam o twig, o twig é utilizado para alterar o template do E-commerce, logo dá para mudar quase tudo, porém algumas coisas são limitadas. ( Pois o twig serve para mexer no layout do template). 

No caso a loja que estou usando é o Tray e estou utilizando o opencode para desenvolver. Se quiser mais informações veja Aqui: http://dev.tray.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/206159587-Iniciando-um-tema

Não acho que estas informações eram necessárias. Por isto não coloquei isto na pergunta pois só iria confundir quem iria responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá, é muito simples.

Apenas faça

```
$('.txt-comjurosde').remove()
```